# Modify Flycheck GCC include path

Tags: c++, emacs, cc, flycheck

I wanted to add project specific includes with a dir local doing this:

```lisp
((c++-mode .
       ( (flycheck-gcc-include-path
          . ( "../engine" "/usr/include/qt"  "/usr/include/qt/QtCore" "/usr/include/qt/QtWidgets" )
          ) )
       ))
```

This works when using flycheck-compile but when using flycheck-buffer it complains: `Error from syntax checker c/c++-gcc: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the stray `"` between `.../qt"` and `"/usr/include/...` actually there in your real code?

Comment: I made a type while coping this my real code now

Comment: I _think_ you need square brackets, to make it an array, rather than a list of strings.

Comment: Please enable the debugger with `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, try again, and add the resulting backtrace to your question.

Comment: I tried it didn't triggered it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me:

```
((c++-mode 
       (flycheck-gcc-include-path "../engine" "/usr/include/qt"  "/usr/include/qt/QtCore" "/usr/include/qt/QtWidgets" ) ))
```

Note the missing "." and extra brackets.